# In Power Automate, How to get linked Test plan / Test Case using User Story ID?

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-devops-rest-api

Unable to get the linked test details for a user story in Power Automate or Rest Api

I am trying to get the linked test details for a user story in Power Automate. I tried using **Get work item children** but it is returning only Child link types not others. I was also searching for ways to do the same using Rest API but couldn't find it in documentation. can you please help on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Query by WIQL method in a Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps action.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Below is an example

Uri

```
@{variables('ProjectName')}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

Body

```
{"query": "SELECT [System.Id],[System.AssignedTo],[System.State],[System.Title],[System.Tags] FROM workitemlinks WHERE ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') AND ([Source].[System.Id] = '@{variables('UserStoryId')}')"}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Expiscornovus, this helps.

Note: There is no link types for Test Plan but for Test Case we can use **Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward** LinkType